# JSP/JSTL - Iterating through a JSONArray with nested JSON Objects

Tags: json, jsp, jstl

This is how my current JSONArray is constructed:

```
{ "exams":[
    { 0:[
        { 0:[
            { "URL": "www.google.com",
              "Date": "July 26, 2017",
              "Heading": "Google"
            },
            { "URL": "www.yahoo.com",
              "Date": "July 27, 2017",
              "Heading": "Yahoo"
            }]
        }]
    }]
}
```

Right now, I am trying to iterate through this by creating links with the heading as the title/text of the a tag.

So far this is what I have:

```
<c:forEach var="exam" items="${exams}" varStatus="counter">
    <c:if test="${!empty exams}">
    <div id="exams${counter.count-1}">
        <a href="${exam.URL}" target="_blank" title="<c:out value="${exam.Date}" />" </a>
        <p>exam.Heading</p>
    </div>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE: Answer below**

Managed to get it working by simply doing all the value grabs with a single forEach statement:

```
<c:forEach var="exam" items="${exams}" varStatus="counter">
    <div id="exams">
        <a href="${exam.URL}" target="_blank" title="<c:out value="${exam.Date}" />">
            <c:out value="${exam.Date}" />
        </a>
        <p> <c:out value="${exam.Heading}" /> </p>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing something like `items="${exams[0][0]}"`? I'm not sure which array you want to iterate over as there's 3 of them, that _should_ get the data in the example though. Otherwise you could simply nest loops.

Comment: I hadn't tried that yet @JamesIves but I managed to get it working. Answer is in the updated question.